# How to Host RASA in AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

Provide the documentation for how to host rasa in aws ec2 instances.

Hosting RASA in AWS EC2 instances.

Whether it should be hosted via docker setup or direct. Also, I'm facing issue in uploading my rasa appication in version management tool like git, gitlab etc..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hosting Rasa on AWS EC2 via Docker:
**Launch an EC2 Instance:**

Log in to your AWS account and navigate to the EC2 dashboard.
Launch a new EC2 instance, preferably using an Amazon Linux 2 AMI.
Make sure to configure security groups to allow inbound traffic on ports 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP), and 443 (HTTPS).
**SSH into the Instance:**

```
ssh -i /path/to/your-key.pem ec2-user@your-ec2-public-ip
```

**Install Docker:**

Follow the official Docker installation instructions for Amazon Linux 2, which can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/amazon-linux-2/).

**Install Docker Compose:**

Install Docker Compose using the instructions found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

**Download and Run Rasa Docker Images:**

Pull the Rasa Docker images from Docker Hub:

```
docker pull rasa/rasa:latest-full
```

Create a docker-compose.yml file to configure your Rasa instance. Here's a basic example:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:latest-full
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    volumes:
      - ./rasa:/app
    command:
      - run
```

Start the Rasa container:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

**Access Your Rasa Instance:**

Rasa should now be running on your EC2 instance. You can access it via http://your-ec2-public-ip:5005.

**Hosting Rasa on AWS EC2 Directly:**
**Launch an EC2 Instance:**

Follow steps 1-2 from the Docker setup above.

**Install Dependencies:**

Install the necessary dependencies for Rasa. This may include Python, pip, and any other libraries required by your specific Rasa project.

**Upload Your Rasa Application to EC2:**

You can upload your Rasa application to the EC2 instance using scp (Secure Copy Protocol) or by creating a Git repository on your local machine and cloning it on the EC2 instance. Make sure to configure your security groups to allow inbound traffic on port 22.

**Set Up and Run Rasa:**

Once your application is on the EC2 instance, navigate to the project directory and run your Rasa application.